# C# Binary File Post Request

Tags: c#, http, http-headers

I am dealing with a third-party API which insists on a binary File Upload request being formatted **without** a `Content-Type` header value of `multipart/form-data`, and with the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: filename*=UTF-8''file.zip
```

`HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.DispositionType` won't allow me to achieve this either because I can't set the values as desired or they set them automatically.

I accept that this API may not be following HTTP Standards but it's not mine and I have no influence over it.

### My attempt which does not work

```cs
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"e:\dev\TestHalfB.docx", FileMode.Open);

        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, <Uri>);
        HttpContent fc = new StreamContent(fs);
        var mpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        mpContent.Add(fc);
        fc.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
        req.Content = fc;
        fc.Headers.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "filename*=UTF-8''TestHalfB.docx";

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        fs.Close();
    }
```

Does anyone know of a lower level API I could use or have any suggestions?

So the crux is how can I set the `Content-Disposition` header to the value I desire.

Comment: What is fiddler showing for your `Content-Disposition` header when you make a request?

Comment: You might be better off with `ByteArrayContent` but what error are you actually receiving?

Comment: Are you getting compiler errors or runtime errors.  Which line(s)?

Comment: The API refuses to accept the request because of the needed header values per my question. The file payload itself is OK. The compiler will not let me set the `fc.Headers.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "filename*=UTF-8''TestHalfB.docx"`. Gives invalid value error.

Answer (score 3):

I had to switch to using `WebRequest`.

```cs
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://cloud.memsource.com/web/api2/v1/projects/{id}/jobs?token={token}");
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Dev\TestHalfB.docx");
    request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "filename*=UTF-8''TestHalfB.docx");
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription.Dump();
```

Comment: After hours of trying everything, this answer also works for uploading images in binary format to Azure DevOps for attachments, but needs `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this.

```
   HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(paramFileStream);

    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", "file1");
        var response = client.PostAsync(actionUrl, formData).Result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the important part of my question is about how to set the headers. Your answer does not attempt to set either of them.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you (or at least get you started, since it's not tested):

```
HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, <Uri>);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"e:\dev\TestHalfB.docx", FileMode.Open))
{
    byte[] fb = new byte[(int)fs.Length]; // assumes your file size will fit into an int
    await fs.ReadAsync(fb, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    req.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fb);
    req.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
    req.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileNameStar = "UTF-8''TestHalfB.docx";

    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(req))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @howcheng but I already tried that and it is not possible to set `req.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.DispositionType` to `filename*=UTF-8''TestHalfB.docx` the compiler gives an invalid value error.

Comment: @phil Do you mean you get an exception at runtime? Because I can't see why the compiler would care. Anyway, it turns out there is a `FileNameStar` property. Try setting that (answer edited with the change). Again, this is not tested.

Comment: Yes sorry, I get a runtime exception. I cannot set `ContentDisposition.FileNameStar` without adding it to a `MultipartFormDataContent` and that always introduces a `Content-Type` header with `multipart/form-data` which this API refuses.